# react router 5 browser back button changing state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

In my application, I have a multi-page form that lives on the URL `http://localhost:3000/form`. When I change pages in the form, the URL remains the same, but the `state` changes to render different views (pages of the form).

A new feature I want to implement is to allow the browser back button to switch views/pages (aka change state) in the multi-page form.

Is this possible? How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Why exactly do you want to keep the same route? If a user wants to get back to the same state they were at via a deep link they would not be able to with this implementation would they?
If you want to use the same route you can at least use # routes to keep track of where in the form the user is. 
Eg. 
http://localhost:3000/form#step1, 
http://localhost:3000/form#step2

then the back button would work to move them back a step.

Comment: It's a product requirement to have the route stay the same. The form is intended to be filled out in order and the user should not be able to access a page in the middle via the URL. They would need to click through to reach it. Users use the browser back button thinking that it will take them to a previous page in the form, but it ends up taking them out of the form.

Comment: I don't think you can hijack the back button due to security concerns. I have had a requirement like this before and I put a "back button" at the top of my form, that way it is just a button that you can control.